# Create Amazon like banner - Refer to Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not a UI developer I normally stay on the backend of things, but I am trying to figure out how to build a simple banner to my site just like how amazon has done. I really like the look and feel to. I assume that comes from CSS side.

I have attached a image from amazon website. On amazon site user can click each "Menu" on the bar and respective banner will nicely show with a slide effect. I have select kindle here and you can click any other option on live site to see exactly what I am referring to. I am not sure where would be a good starting point.[image]

Comment: Can't say I have ever met a UI Developer that doesn't know CSS or JS, Designers sure.. but anyway.. your question can ultimately be handled a boat load of ways. Anything from pure HTML/CSS and landing on a page with a click, to JS, CSS, HTML, to PHP HTML CSS or any combination there of (if PHP isn't in play then choose your backend scripting and replace PHP with that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of jquery plugins that do just this - http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-slideshow/. However, here's a little one I just built for fun:

http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/GLmed/

It's only got the basics. You click a link and it slides. For that the css and jquery are just a few lines long. I guess it should be easy to customize.

Comment: Thanks for a great example and guidance towards right direction.